# adding an autoincrement field in mySQL with prefix

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to add an auto increment field in one of the columns in MySQL which will act as the primary key of my table.I saw the post which describes how to do this using triggers. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: No. auto_increments are numbers, and cannot have any non-numeric values in them. therefore you need a trigger to add any prefixes/suffixes AFTER the id's been generated.

Comment: In some database systems you can use Sequences and a default column value to do this; I don't know if MySQL supports that or not

Comment: Could you have a separate column that has your 'internal key' to relate your data together? Why? Leave the database engine to look after relationships between tables. You look after relationships between your data?

Comment: If you want it all in one swoop (one insert), you need a separate control table with a lock. It becomes over engineering nonsense. I could show you but it would be a tremendous waste of time for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I know the MyISAM storage engine used to, not sure if it still does, do something like what you want.

It is not in the same field, but if the primary key is a composite that contains an auto-increment field, the field's value is based on the other values in the key (don't recall if it is only the preceding ones in the key definition, or all).

```
Simple example:
PK: name, auto_id
Data ends up being something like:
red, 1
blue, 1
red, 2
red, 3
blue, 2
yellow, 1
```